# Can the VPN administrators see what I'm surfing on web when I connect to their VPN?

Tags: vpn, security, internet

I’m working on a new job and they gave me the choice of using my own computer for working. Once I don't need to install any software I chose to use my MacBook.

But, when I start a project with a new client I had to install a VPN for having access to their intranet from my house. But if I use my personal computer, I’m afraid of my personal data be available for the VPN administrator.

Is it any way possible? Should I get an office computer for working from now on?

Comment: any traffic that goes through the VPN can possibly be available to the VPN administrator.

Comment: What VPN client is it, Cisco AnyConnect, Fortinet, something else? Do you know whether it’s a “split tunneling” setup?

Comment: Thanks, Guys. There's a "split tunnel disabled" option but I don't use this one, so I figure it out that it's a split tunneling setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are safe if split tunneling is enabled and *not* disabled.

#### Most work-related VPNs use split tunneling to ensure only the traffic that is related to the work VPN is going trough the VPN connection. But if split tunneling is disabled *all* traffic will flow through the VPN connection.

> “…I had to install a VPN for having access to their intranet from my house. But if I use my personal computer, I’m afraid of my personal data be available for the VPN administrator.”

If you use the VPN to connect to their office intranet and split tunneling is enabled, that is the only time/way they could ever monitor traffic. And the only traffic they can monitor is the traffic that is specifically passing through their VPN. They cannot see the non-VPN traffic.

#### This all assumes  the VPN will be setup with the sane/default split tunnel settings.

For example, with split tunneling if you worked for `example.com` and then surf over to `linkedin.com` or `gmail.com` the only traffic the company would ever possibly be able to monitor would be traffic to `example.com`. VPNs like the ones used for intranet access only care about the internal hostnames they are giving you access to. They cannot monitor anything else.

#### But you disable split tunneling *all* traffic would flow through the VPN connection.

This is the insane/non-default way of dealing with VPNs because network admins in offices do not want to deal with *all* traffic from a VPN client flowing through. Yeah, that *could* be enabled for spying on employee traffic. But most network admins don’t do that and are more concerned about a VPN client gobbling up more traffic that needed.

Imagine being a network admin and seeing that after hours workers are streaming movies trough the office VPN? Who wants to deal with that?

#### When the MacBook is yours, just delete the VPN software and enjoy the MacBook!

That said, when the MacBook becomes your own personal device, you can just uninstall the VPN software from your MacBook and should be 100% fine. Heck, if you even left the VPN software installed but didn’t connect to their VPN you would be fine.

Assuming split tunneling is in play — and it is safe to assume that but feel free to check your VPN client settings — the only risk of snooping would only be on the VPN connection and if the VPN is connected to the office intranet.

Comment: Got it. My questions is because I need to connect the VPN to access an internal website for working. But if I access another page from safari, for personal use like LinkedIn or instagram, with the VPN turned on and connected, they can see my access, right? When my work time finishes I turned off the VPN and force close the VPN app and at this moment I know its fine to use my MacBook as I want.

Comment: “But if I access another page from safari, for personal use like LinkedIn or instagram, with the VPN turned on and connected, they can see my access, right?” Nope. A VPN would only pay attention to data on that intranet network. So if you worked for `example.com` and then surf to `linkedin.com` or `gmail.com` the only traffic they would ever possibly be able to monitor would be `example.com`. VPNs like the ones used for intranet access only care about the internal hostnames they are giving you access to. They cannot monitor anything else.

Comment: Oh!! Got it now! That was a great explanation, thank you! I have the habit of doing personal things during the workday just like I usually work on my free time as well.

Comment: This is _technically_ true, but in practice misleading – there is **no actual guarantee** that the VPN is actually configured for the company's intranet _only_; it could very easily be just setting up a default route that'll carry all traffic over the VPN whether it belongs to the company or not. You have to specifically check what routes the VPN client installs when it's "connected" (keeping in mind that the configuration can be changed on the VPN server).

Comment: @user1686 Very good point. I just reworked my answer to factor in split tunneling into the explanation. As long as split tunneling is active, no worries. Without split tunneling _all_ traffic flows through the VPN which is a risk. But most offices don’t want to deal with all traffic from all workers being piped through their VPN.